# eventstore container exists upon starting

Tags: docker, apple-m1, eventstoredb

I started an eventstore service with docker-compose and it exits right after starting. the other services are working fine, but the event store is the only one that stops. I just started using an M1 chip macbook air and suspecting it's the reason.

These are the service logs:

```
> Executing task: docker logs --tail 1000 -f efb9a01f49d5383851f28e9badbd0934b1bc8a7b7cf1db018ed3a7b0436df25d <

[

    1, 1,14:24:17.218,FTL] Host terminated unexpectedly.
System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at EventStore.Common.Log.EventStoreLoggerConfiguration.Initialize(String logsDirectory, String componentName, String logConfig) in /build/src/EventStore.Common/Log/EventStoreLoggerConfiguration.cs:line 58
   at EventStore.Core.EventStoreHostedService`1.Init(TOptions options) in /build/src/EventStore.Core/EventStoreHostedService.cs:line 89
   at EventStore.ClusterNode.ClusterVNodeHostedService.Init(ClusterNodeOptions options) in /build/src/EventStore.ClusterNode/ClusterVNodeHostedService.cs:line 44
   at EventStore.Core.EventStoreHostedService`1..ctor(String[] args) in /build/src/EventStore.Core/EventStoreHostedService.cs:line 45
   at EventStore.ClusterNode.ClusterVNodeHostedService..ctor(String[] args) in /build/src/EventStore.ClusterNode/ClusterVNodeHostedService.cs:line 35
   at EventStore.ClusterNode.Program.Main(String[] args) in /build/src/EventStore.ClusterNode/Program.cs:line 22

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alpha build is available that lets you run the Docker image on MacBook with an M1 chipset.
You have to use the GitHub Container registry image: https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/pkgs/container/eventstore/7973829.

Docker image: `ghcr.io/eventstore/eventstore:20.6.1-alpha.0.69-arm64v8`

Example how to run the command:

```sh
docker run --name esdb-node -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 \
    ghcr.io/eventstore/eventstore:20.6.1-alpha.0.69-arm64v8 --insecure --run-projections=All \
    --enable-external-tcp --enable-atom-pub-over-http
```

Comment: Great! Happy to read that! Could you also mark it as the correct answer on SO? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with docker running on M1. We are currently working on providing a native arm64 build and container. You can track that progress here: https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/pull/3076